# JAXB object containment to xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to print the xml from java using jaxb.

The code I have is as follows:

```
public class MyXMLGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBPojo jaxbPojo = new JAXBPojo();
        jaxbPojo.setName("setName");
        jaxbPojo.setId(345);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBPojo.class);

        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(jaxbPojo, System.out);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class JAXBPojo {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    @XmlElement(namespace="ddd")
    private Address address;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress() {
        address = new Address();
        address.setHouseName("setHouseName");
        address.setStateName("setStateName");
        address.setLocalityName("setLocalityName");
        address.setAreaName("setAreaName");
        address.setCityName("setCityName");

    }

}

@XmlElement
public class Address {

    private String houseName;
    private String streetName;
    private String localityName;
    private String areaName;
    private String cityName;
    private String districtName;
    private String stateName;
    private String countryName;
    public String getHouseName() {
        return houseName;
    }
    public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getLocalityName() {
        return localityName;
    }
    public void setLocalityName(String localityName) {
        this.localityName = localityName;
    }
    public String getAreaName() {
        return areaName;
    }
    public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
        this.areaName = areaName;
    }
    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }
    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
    public String getDistrictName() {
        return districtName;
    }
    public void setDistrictName(String districtName) {
        this.districtName = districtName;
    }
    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }
    public void setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }
    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }
    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

}
```

I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxbPojo xmlns:ns2="ddd">
    <id>345</id>
    <name>setName</name>
</jaxbPojo>
```

But when I supply value for address class in the main method, I do get the address as well in the output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxbPojo>
    <address>
        <areaName>setAreaName</areaName>
        <cityName>setCityName</cityName>
        <houseName>setHouseName</houseName>
        <localityName>setLocalityName</localityName>
        <stateName>setStateName</stateName>
    </address>
    <id>345</id>
    <name>setName</name>
</jaxbPojo>
```

what changes do I have to do to get it working in the current case where I get values for address class in jaxbpojo?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You never call `setAddress()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want but I would change setAddress to:

```
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

main to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBPojo jaxbPojo = new JAXBPojo();
    jaxbPojo.setName("setName");
    jaxbPojo.setId(345);
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setHouseName("setHouseName");
    address.setStateName("setStateName");
    address.setLocalityName("setLocalityName");
    address.setAreaName("setAreaName");
    address.setCityName("setCityName");
    jaxbPojo.setAddress(address);
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBPojo.class);

    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    m.marshal(jaxbPojo, System.out);
}
```